# Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a homework assingment. But i didn't get it exactly what i have to do.

"create a PivotTable with the smallest sales per agent and per article. there may be no grand totals shown. the field names must be in the PivotTable."

i did something like that. but it didn't seems like correct.

this is the table!

```
Row Labels  Min of Sales
1-          
  1         12589
  2         14700
2-         
  1         12300
  2         12365




   Date      Artikel    agent   Channel  Sales
    3.01.2015   1   1   1   45612
    3.01.2015   2   2   1   12365
    4.01.2015   1   2   1   12345
    4.01.2015   1   2   2   45230
    5.01.2015   2   1   2   45610
    6.01.2015   2   1   1   74102
    6.01.2015   1   2   1   12300
    7.01.2015   1   1   2   12589
    7.01.2015   2   2   1   45600
    9.01.2015   2   1   2   45600
    9.01.2015   1   2   2   65400
    10.01.2015  2   1   2   54600
    10.01.2015  1   2   1   56400
    13.01.2015  2   1   2   74100
    13.01.2015  1   2   2   14700
    14.01.2015  1   1   2   32500
    14.01.2015  1   2   1   65200
18.01.2015  2   2   2   36900
18.01.2015  2   1   1   25800
22.01.2015  2   1   1   14700
22.01.2015  1   1   2   41700
23.01.2015  1   2   2   52800
23.01.2015  1   1   1   63900
26.01.2015  1   2   2   35700
26.01.2015  2   2   1   15900
27.01.2015  1   1   1   97100
28.01.2015  1   2   1   31700
31.01.2015  1   1   1   93100
```

Comment: "Pivot Tables for Beginners" - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peNTp5fuKFg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Dont Want Grand Total, you can right Click on Row Labels and select Pivot Table Option and Select Totals & Filters And Uncheck the Show Grand Totals for Column.

Filed Names you can Manually Edit or You Can Choose Custom Name by Selecting Value Field Settings.
 [image]

Comment: great. thanks. but what about that part ""create a PivotTable with the smallest sales per agent"

Comment: Select `Agent` in RowLabels and `Sales` in Values field, and also uncheck the show grand totals for rows.

Comment: allright.I edited what i wrote it at the first.Now its correct i guess

Comment: For smallest sales per agent and per article, Select Agent in Row Labels and Select Article in Row Label Below Agent and then Select Sales in Values Field, and Click on `Sales` in value Field, Select Value Field Settings and Select Min in the Dropdown.

Comment: OK I edited my first message again. I think this  time everything is allright.

Comment: Yes, Try as above , you will get required result

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the Agent and Artikel as the row labels, and remove the date.

Comment: I changed it.but what about "smallest sales" per agent and artikel?